# React Native app crash on ios 13.3.1 after I updated to latest ios version

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am running react native app on ios simulator(13.3) and on ipad(13.1.1). on simulator it is working fine . Previously it was working fine on ipad also but ipad got updated to 13.3.1 . Since than on ipad it is crashing on white screen within fraction of seconds. Any idea to fix it?